# How to make CSS triangles (with borders) compatible across browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser, flowchart

I was able to create a neat pointy flow-chart, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/R8Gx3/3/

However, the rendering is not consistent across the major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE).

Any thoughts on how to achieve this same effect but in a more reliable way?

Obviously I could use images, but I prefer CSS wherever possible since it's easier to edit colors in CSS (rather than create new images).

I can't just use a triangle character since there is a textured background behind the elements, so I need transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For modern browsers you could use CSS tranforms (*for IE that would be 9 and above*)

so you make a box with top/right border and rotate it 45 degrees.

This way you can simplify the html and just apply the arrows with `:after` and `:before` (*each one being one of the tips*)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/FJEFP/1/

Comment: I'll give you "best answer" since you made a good effort, even though this still doesn't achieve what I'm trying to do.  (See how it looks funky with a background? http://jsfiddle.net/FJEFP/2/)

Comment: @Ryan, you can change the background-color of `div.left:before` but yes.. it is not truly transparent.. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/FJEFP/3/

Comment: I'm very impressed anyway.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have better luck placing UTF-8 triangles, two at one end and one at the other, rather than depending on border-hacks.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/browsertest.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes

Comment: Updated the demo link and added a note about how I need transparency.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you form using opacity on these characters as well.